# PhP function for Youtube Embed Video

Tags: php, database, youtube, embed

I am trying to preg_match() youtube videos that are stored in a database column.

The database column is named "trailer_url"

```
 <?php
//$url = '';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT trailer_url FROM top_sites");
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$storeArray[] =  $row['trailer_url'];  
}
//$trailer_url = $_POST['trailerUrl'];
preg_grep('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $storeArray, $matches);
$id = $matches[1]; ?>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a trailer_url and what you aim to preg_match out of this url ?

Comment: Trailer_url is any video you want from youtube but they are stored in database in a column named trailer_url "`trailer_url` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=7YAVn466YBc',"

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like...

```
$id = preg_replace("/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/embed\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i", "$1", $row['trailer_url']);
```

This will store the video id from `https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=7YAVn466YBc` in `$id`.

Comment: And what I put on src?`<iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $id ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: `<iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $id ?>?rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/C9b4JLit Something it strange it doesn't want to find the video from youtube I get error "An error has ocurred please try again later"

Comment: Make sure the URL and ID for the video is correct. be sure the url is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=[ID]`

Comment: I need a function that transform the simple link with /embed cuz users don't know that they must add the link embed.